# Changing state of a radibutton with ToggleButtonExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm using  ajax togglebuttonextender to set image to radibuttons. 
In javascript when I change the status of radibutton, togglebuttonextender status is not changed..

is there a way to set checked false of togglebuttonextender in js?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following example which demonstrates in javascript how to:

- Get the state of a togglebuttonextender,
- Change the state of a togglebuttonextender, and
- Set the togglebuttonextender to false.

  ```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
          <title></title>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function getcheckstate() {
                  var e = $find("tb");
                  alert(e._element.checked);
              }

              function change() {
                  var e = $find("tb");
                  e._element.click();
                  //e._element.checked = (!e._element.checked); // <--- Dont use this method because it requires you hover your mouse over the image in order for it to update.
              }

              function changetofalse() {
                  var e = $find("tb");
                  if (e._element.checked) e._element.click();
              }
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div>
              <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
              <asp:ToggleButtonExtender
                  ID="tbe"
                  TargetControlID="CheckBox1"
                  ImageWidth="22"
                  ImageHeight="22"
                  CheckedImageUrl="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1050/pidgin_old_tango_smilies/24/good.png"
                  UncheckedImageUrl="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1050/pidgin_old_tango_smilies/24/bad.png"
                  runat="server"
                  BehaviorID="tb" />
              <br /><br />
              <input type="button" onclick="getcheckstate()" value="Get Checkbox Checked State" />
              <br />
              <input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change Checkbox Checked State" />
              <br />
              <input type="button" onclick="changetofalse()" value="Set Checkbox Checked State To False" />
          </div>
          </form>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Call other extender's `_checkChangedHandler()` method on click of radio button in JavaScript.